# {reloadOnSearch: false} equivalent param for $state.go()

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to do some filter operation on my page and just want to change the URL and not to reload the page.

I can configure my routing to use reloadOnSearch: false and not reload the UI, and just change the URL.

```
.state('testing', {
                    url: '/testing?&param',
                    templateUrl: 'some_template',
                    reloadOnSearch: false
                })
```

This works completely fine, but due to some reason I do not want to mention this in state param, and instead want to pass this value as parameter.

I tried passing {reload: false} to

```
$state.go('testing', {param: 123}, {reload: false})
```

But it doesn't seems to be working. Its changing the state and so reloading the page.

Can anyone please help me to find the equivalent syntax for {reloadOnSearch: false} for $state.go() (or some equivalent)

Answer (score 0):

In case, we need to change params and change url - but keep the views untouched... we do use child state. (check the [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/mIohaTi9vg0DgF1lNpdD?p=preview))

```
  .state('testing', {
      url: "/testing",
      templateUrl: 'parent.tpl.html',
  })
  .state('testing.child', { 
      url: "?param",
      //params: {
      //  param: null,
      //},
      template: '',
  })
```

And with these links

```
<a ui-sref="testing">testing</a>
<a ui-sref="testing.child({param:123})">
<a ui-sref="testing.child({param:987})">
```

And these links will change the url, but parent template (view) will be the same. Check it [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/mIohaTi9vg0DgF1lNpdD?p=preview)